# Handling non-uniform frequency data

Tags: time-series, interpolation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have some medical data (heart rates) at non-uniform intervals (usually readings every few min at the start of the study and several readings a minute toward the end). The timing and when the change occurs is not the same for all patients. I want to calculate a simple AUC (probably just a linear interpolation).

Is it best to:

- use all the data available (this seems like it may over- or under-estimate for patients with more higher frequency data points);
- interpolate (downsample the high freq data) to some uniform time points across all patients (though this will likely discard much of the data);
- interpolate (downsample the high freq data) to some uniform frequency across patients but different time points for each patient (still ignores some data but at least makes use of what is there for an individual); or
- something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would exclude option B for sure, because data are extremely valuable and usually we do everything possible in order to avoid discarding them (also, with all other conditions being equal, the less data the more potential standard errors), so the option B has a very high cost (in order to regularize the series you artificially sacrifice data quality, this does not seem to be a good deal). Can I ask you, even if I am not expert about medical studies, why are you saying that if you use all the data then you will likely over or underestimate something for the patients with **more** data?

Comment: The issue also depends on what the purpose of your study is. For example, if you need to model the heartbeat time-series for the average patients and you care about the value of time-series coefficients, this is a problem as you do not have a beat every x seconds for each patient. BUT if you are only looking at whether the heartbeat changes significantly for the average patient, then you can estimate the series for each patient with the available info and then test the significance in coefficient change for each. Then calculate the percentage of patients for which the change is significant

Comment: In option 1, I should have possibly said the under- or over-estimation will be for the patients with less data. Is it fair to use all the data if there is more in some patients?

I'm not interested in beat-to-beat variability; just the overall rate over the study period. Patients were randomised into different groups and we're interested in the AUC of HR over time. So you think using all the data, even though some patients have more high-frequency information, is reasonable?

Comment: So what are you trying to do here? AUC is just a measure, obtained from a model. What is your model? What are you modeling?

Comment: Exactly if you clarify a little bit what AUC you are measuring and for what, more details on the problem are needed here.. what are you classifying? And why a time series is used here? Maybe you are not trying to predict heart rates so you are not using a time series, but just trying to classify cases of heart rates changes. anyway if I understand correctly what you mean by “I am not interested in beat-beat.. just the overall change” personally I would go for option 1, as you can calculate the overall change from inception to end for each patient even if freq is not the same, and then average

Comment: Also because as usual, the more info you use the better it is, and trying to democratize the frequency in exchange for using less info for each patient, would lead you to the higher risk of over/under estimating even when you can bear a smaller risk of under/over estimating because you have more info.. so it is counterproductive, unless you are required to. You were required to, in case you had to model the beat-beat with a time series model, but I understand that this is not your case, if you just want a measure of change from beginning to end..

Comment: We are looking at the effects of different stimuli on heart rate. Due to the way we've collected the data, they are not uniform - as described.
AUC is one measure and it will be the area under the baseline heart rate over the time of the interventions.

What I am hearing is that the non-uniformity is not such a big deal compared with discarding data, and so we should use it all. Is that right?

Thanks!